# add events fullcalendar by json feed

Tags: php, json, yii

I am newbie in yii and fullcalendar, i have 
- events.php:`

```
    try {
        $events = array();

        $query  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT schedules.start_at, schedules.end_at, timetables.name,terminals.name FROM schedules, terminals, timetables WHERE schedules.terminal_id = terminals.id and timetables.id = schedules.timetable_id");
        $rows = $query->queryAll();
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $e = array();
            $e['title'] = $row['name'];
            $e['start'] = $row['start_at'];
            // Merge the event array into the return array
            array_push($events, $e);
        }
        echo json_encode($events);
        exit();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!";
    }
    Yii::app()->end();
}
?>`
```

I can feed json from events.php in class calendar.php

```
events:
      {
        url:'events.php'
      }
```

Please help me how to call json "url:" by yii.

Answer (score 0):

you make a request like this

> /index.php/events/getevents?id=3

(or like /getevents/id/3), you will get back a JSON formatted response, like this:

```
{"id":"3","name":"something","start_at":"05/11/2016 10:00:00"}
```

And now you have a real simple JSON API